# How to display all entries within a given category

Tags: categories, category

I've got a category group called `allcategories`, inside of this is two categories called `design` and `photo`.

I'm trying to filter all entries in the section `projects` by the category `photo' but none of my permutations are working :(

```
<section class="index">

    {% set category = craft.categories.group('allcategories').find('photos') %}
    {% set projects = craft.entries.section('projects').relatedTo(category).find() %}

    {% for entry in projects %}
        <p><a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a></p>
    {% endfor %}

</section>
```

Answer (score 5):

Your mistake is in getting the category. Instead of what you have try:

```
{% set category = craft.categories.group('allcategories').slug('photos').find() %}
```

Getting elements in Craft use ElementCriteriaModel and `find()`, `first()`, `last()`, &c. do not accept any parameters (though `nth()` is an exception to this). So you need to search by other fields in the element as per the [docs](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/elementcriteriamodel#setting-the-parameters).

You may also want to make sure that the slug of the category group is not camel case (`allCategories` as opposed to `allcategories`).